# Lost all tables when upgrading PostgreSQL from v11 12

Tags: postgresql, macos

I upgraded Postgres and now it doesn't show any tables. Can anyone help?

This is the error:

```
Error: Upgrading postgresql data from 11 to 12 failed!
 ==> Removing empty postgresql initdb database...
 ==> Moving postgresql data back from /usr/local/var/postgres.old to /usr/local/var/postgres...
 Error: Failure while executing; `/usr/local/opt/postgresql/bin/pg_upgrade -r -b /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql@11/11.6/bin -B /usr/local/opt/postgresql/bin -d /usr/local/var/postgres.old -D /usr/local/var/postgres -j 4` exited with 1.
```

Comment: Which operating system are you using? And how exactly did you run the upgrade?

Comment: Mac OSX and brew reinstall postgresql

Comment: Please provide OS versions, Postgres version (before and after update) and the default column descriptions (aka. datatypes).